# need some simple help understanding a bit of pre-PHP5 code

Tags: php, legacy-code, deprecated

I was turned on to **nstrees** from another question, and have been working through the script. It was last updated in 2005 and relied on some stuff that has since apparently been deprecated like `HTTP_POST_VARS` which I wasn't immediately familiar with since I've been doing PHP for only a little less than a year.

Anyways, the coding style seems weird to my rookie eyes, and I'd like a second opinion on what part of this function does:

```
// returns the first node that matches the '$whereclause'.
// The WHERE clause can optionally contain ORDER BY or LIMIT clauses too.
function nstGetNodeWhere ($thandle, $whereclause) {
    $noderes['l'] = 0;
    $noderes['r'] = 0;
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$thandle['table']." WHERE ".$whereclause);
    if (!$res) { // problem area 1
        _prtError();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { // problem area 2
            $noderes['l'] = $row[$thandle['lvalname']];
            $noderes['r'] = $row[$thandle['rvalname']];
        }
    }
    return $noderes;
}
```

In the above code I marked the spots I'm not quite sure about as `// problem area x`, everything else is the original script.

Regarding PA1, is that just a check on whether the query was successfully run?

And PA2, NetBeans gives me a warning *"Possible accidental assignment, assignments in conditions should be avoided."* ... so I promptly changed that from `=` to `==` and of course broke the script, heh.

Thinking about it, I guess it's just another error check on `$res`, this time to make sure that some data was actually returned?

Lastly, is this bizarre PHP or am I just too green to grok it?

Thanks dude(tte)s!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Area 1 is exactly what you think it is. It checks if the query ran successfully. Look at the documentation for [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) (since you use Netbeans you can also highlight the function name in the editor and hit F2 to get an inline popup). You're looking for the "Return Values" section. Over there it says it will return FALSE (the boolean FALSE) on any errors.

Checking

```
if (!$res)
```

is the same as checking for

```
if ($res == false)
```

Ideally you should be checking for

```
if ($res === false)
```

because it's safer since PHP is very relaxed about variables == false, but I'd rather not confuse you with that right now. If you'd like you can start by reading about [strong typing](http://www.otton.org/2008/08/06/stupid-php-tricks-true-false-comparison/).

Problem Area 2 is pretty common but will show a warning in Netbeans, yes. What it's doing is assigning a value from mysql_fetch_array() into $row, and checking if *that* is now true or false, while also letting you use that same value now in $row in the following code block inside the if().

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation for PA2. It was the only one of the 3 posted that really helped me "get it." I didn't realize that the construction was actually a 2 step action (assign, check). Makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code can load articles then sort them into a 'left-right' array so it can be printed in a two column layout. Maybe. :)

Yep, PA1 is checking if the query was successful or not. PA2 is simply fetching the actual row.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$res) { // problem area 1
```

mysql_query returns a false if it fails to execute the SQL query. This is basically a test for not (!) any value other than false, so the if test will match if there was an error in mysql_query and execute the print error branch of the code

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { // problem area 2
```

Assigns the next row from the resultset to $row; or sets $row to false if no more rows in the resultset, in which case the "if test" will be false